# Canvas and div blocks not aligning in grid

Tags: css, html, html5-canvas

On my website's sidebar, my plan is to have canvas and div blocks aligned in this formation:

```
-----------------------------------
|               |                 |
|  Canvas       |     Canvas      |
|_______________|_________________|
|                                 |
|              Div                |
|_________________________________|
|               |                 |
|  Canvas       |     Canvas      |
|_______________|_________________|
```

But in actual implementation, there is a line break after each element, as shown here: http://jsfiddle.net/Uy4Jz/1/

The CSS controlling these blocks is shown here:

```
#engineer {
    width: 50%;
    height: 150px;
    background: #060;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
}

#programmer {
    width: 50%;
    height: 150px;
    background: #006;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
}

#name {
    width: 100%;
    height: 75px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
}

#musician {
    width: 50%;
    height: 150px;
    background: #600;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
}

#leader {
    width: 50%;
    height: 150px;
    background: #660;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
}
```

How can I remove the line breaks and/or spacing for the desired layout?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove the newlines between your canvas elements:

```
<div id = "sidebar">
<canvas id = "engineer"></canvas><canvas id = "programmer"></canvas>
<div id = "name">Name Here</div>
<canvas id = "musician"></canvas><canvas id = "leader"></canvas>
</div>
```

Comment: That worked. Thank you! Didn't think that would be it, but I guess a newline is almost the same as a space.